# commonModalDialogClose(SP.UI.DialogResult.OK, someValue) throws error

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

In SharePoint 2010 I have a visual web part that uses `SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog`

The dialog shows up fine but when I try to close the dialog using

`SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogClose(SP.UI.DialogResult.OK, someValue)`

I get an error that says

> Unable to get value of the property 'OK': object is null or undefined

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> A quick/hacky workaround would be to use 1 which stands for
>   SP.UI.DialogResult.OK

Thanks, I was able to get this to work using numbers instead of SP.UI.DialogResult.OK.

For example...

`SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogClose(0,'Canceled the dialog.');` is like using SP.UI.DialogResult.cancel

`SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogClose(1,'Yay Success!');` is like using SP.UI.DialogResult.OK

`SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogClose(-1,'Uh oh... Error');` is like using SP.UI.DialogResult.invalid

Answer (score 6):

You need to include the SharePoint JS file *SP.UI.Dialog.js* on your "dialog page".

```
<SharePoint:ScriptLink Name="SP.UI.Dialog.js" runat="server" />
```

or

```
<script src="/_layouts/SP.UI.Dialog.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

A quick/hacky workaround would be to use `1` which stands for `SP.UI.DialogResult.OK`.