# How to update UI from Async function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, asynchronous, csom

I am developing sharepoint hosted app in sharepoint 2013. I am using following function to upload file in sharepoint.

```
 self.UploadFile = function () {

            // Suppose my business logic goes here

            appWebContext.load(files);
            appWebContext.executeQueryAsync(
            function () {

                alert("All files are uploaded.");
                SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogClose();
                //SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogClose();
                //window.close();

            },

           function (error, errorMes) {
               //SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogClose();
               //$("#btnMigrate").val("Migrate Class");
               //$("#btnMigrate").removeAttr("disabled");
               //alert(errorMes.get_message());
               alert("Oooooops... it looks like something went wrong uploading your file.");
           });



    };
```

The above code works fine. It shows the messsage 'All files are uploaded'. Then it gives error on `SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogClose()`; In above code when I call `SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogClose();` in `appWebContext.executeQueryAsync` function I get the error 'Javascript runtime error : Function is undefined'. Can anyone please tell me how to update UI from async function in javascript? Can you please provide me any code or link ?

Comment: Can you please show only the part of code which is relevant to the actual problem?

Comment: It still has a huge chunk of code.

Comment: Rmoved unnecessary code. Please see

Answer (score 0):

The `SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogClose()` method takes a "result" as a parameter.

`SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogClose(1,'Yay Success!');` is like using `SP.UI.DialogResult.OK`

Also, to manipulate the dialog window you'll need to have `<script src="/_layouts/SP.UI.Dialog.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` loaded somewhere.

See related post:  [commonModalDialogClose(SP.UI.DialogResult.OK, someValue) throws error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8901387/commonmodaldialogclosesp-ui-dialogresult-ok-somevalue-throws-error)